# Tricky integrals in the form $\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{(1+(k^2+q^2-2kq\cos{\theta})a^2)^n}}d\theta$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have two integrals that I need to solve. $q$ and $k$ are both arbitrary positive real numbers.

> $$\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{(1+(k^2+q^2-2kq\cos{\theta})a^2)^2}}d\theta$$
> $$\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{(1+(k^2+q^2+2kq\cos{\theta})a^2)^4}}d\theta $$

I don't really have any good ideas on how to approach this, but when I tried using Mathematica I got the following results
$$\frac{2}{1+a^4(k^2-q^2)^2+2a^2(k^2+q^2)}$$

$$\frac{1}{6a^2kq}\Big(\frac{1}{(1+a^2(k-q)^2)^3}-\frac{1}{(1+a^2(k+q)^2)^3}\Big)$$
for the first and second integral respectively, but with a bunch of additional conditions so I would prefer to solve the integral using pen and paper to be sure about the correctness of all the intermediary steps.

Maybe the Mathematica solutions can give a hint on how to approach the manual solution. Any tips even just on how to start or approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: hm... do you see a u substitution?

Comment: $$\left(C+a\cos\theta\right)'=-a\sin\theta$$

Comment: Try the substitution $u = 1+(k^2+q^2 \pm 2kq\cos{\theta})a^2$.

Comment: thank you everyone, that made it easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the integral
\begin{align}
I(x)=&\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{x+(k^2+q^2-2kq\cos{\theta})a^2}}d\theta
=\frac1{2kqa^2}\ln \frac{x+(k+q)^2a^2}{x+(k-q)^2a^2}
\end{align}
Then

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{(1+(k^2+q^2-2kq\cos{\theta})a^2)^2}}d\theta\\
=&-\frac{d I(x)}{dx}\bigg|_{x=1}=\frac{2}{1+a^4(k^2-q^2)^2+2a^2(k^2+q^2)}
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi{\frac{\sin{\theta}}{(1+(k^2+q^2+2kq\cos{\theta})a^2)^4}}d\theta\\
=&-\frac16 \frac{d^3 I(x)}{dx^3}\bigg|_{x=1}=\frac{1}{6a^2kq}\Big(\frac{1}{(1+a^2(k-q)^2)^3}-\frac{1}{(1+a^2(k+q)^2)^3}\Big)
\end{align}